# Combine values in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a large dataset with different columns that represent questions from a questionnaire:

```
dt <- data.table(q32_1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
                 q32_2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                 q32_3 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
                 q22_1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                 q22_2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
                 q22_3 = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

different questions has different levels of options that people could choose when answering the questions.

I want for q22(1-3) combine value 1 and 2 so they both are 1 how can I do so?

Comment: You can use `for(cl in grep("^q22", names(dt))) set(dt, which(dt[[cl]]==2), cl, 1)`

Answer (score 2):

Loop through subset of column names, and change 2s to 1:

```
cols <- grep("^q22", names(dt), value = TRUE)

dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(i) ifelse(i %in% 1:2, 1, i)), .SDcols = cols ]

dt
#    q32_1 q32_2 q32_3 q22_1 q22_2 q22_3
# 1:     1     1     1     1     1     1
# 2:     2     2     2     1     1     1
# 3:     3     3     3     3     3     3
# 4:     4     4     4     4     4     4
# 5:     5     5     5     1     1     1
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`'s `set()`:

```
for (col in names(dt)) {
  if (col %like% "^q22_[1-3]$") set(dt, which(dt[[col]] == 2), col, value = 1)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try the below code

```r
library(tidyverse)

dt %>% mutate(across(starts_with('q22'), ~ifelse(.x==2,1,.x)))

#output

   q32_1 q32_2 q32_3 q22_1 q22_2 q22_3
1:     1     1     1     1     1     1
2:     2     2     2     1     1     1
3:     3     3     3     3     3     3
4:     4     4     4     4     4     4
5:     5     5     5     1     1     1
```